# Can integer operations (eg addition or subtraction) be performed on malloc buffers?

Tags: c, bmp

To learn about JPEG compression, I downloaded a simple BMP/JPEG [encoder](https://github.com/rockcarry/ffjpeg) that I have been examining.  I have several questions, hopefully someone can help me with. I'm not a trained computer scientist, just a hobby programmer. Grateful for any help.

The following code reads a bitmap, I left some information out for brevity. I understand that a bitmap header is written as a struct, so the components can be read directly to variables without iterating.

BYTE is a typedef for uint8_t

```
    int bmp_load(BMP *pb, char *file)
{
    BMPFILEHEADER header = {0};
    FILE         *fp     = NULL;
    BYTE         *pdata  = NULL;
    int           i;

    fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (!fp) return -1;

    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, fp);
    pb->width  = header.biWidth;
    pb->height = header.biHeight;
    pb->stride = ALIGN(header.biWidth * 3, 4);
    pb->pdata  = malloc(pb->stride * pb->height);// allocate a byte for each element of bitmap?
    if (pb->pdata) {
        pdata  = (BYTE*)pb->pdata + pb->stride * pb->height; // Title question: Cast pdata as uint8_t buffer but what is the addition for? I think it has to do with padding a BMP file.  Without addition there is a bus error: 10 
        for (i=0; i<pb->height; i++) {
            pdata -= pb->stride; // What is the subtraction for? 
            fread(pdata, pb->stride, 1, fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return pb->pdata ? 0 : -1; // If pdata was being modified in the for loop, why is pb->pdata returned? 
}
```

I have my questions as comments in the code and also pasted below. 
What is the addition for? I think it has to do with padding a BMP file.  Without addition there is a bus error: 10

```
    pdata  = (BYTE*)pb->pdata + pb->stride * pb->height;
```

What is the subtraction for?

```
    pdata -= pb->stride;
```

And finally, why is pb->pdata returned but its actually pdata that is modified in the code?

Comment: `bmp_load` does not return `pb->pdata`. It returns `0` or `-1` depending on the value of `pb->pdata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rewrite of the function that might be easier to understand.

```
int bmp_load(BMP *pb, char *file)
{
    FILE* = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (!fp) return -1;

    BMPFILEHEADER header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, fp);
    pb->width = header.biWidth;
    pb->height = header.biHeight;
    pb->stride = ALIGN(header.biWidth * 3, 4);
    pb->pdata = malloc(pb->stride * pb->height);

    if (!pb->pdata) return -1;

    for (int i = pb->height - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        BYTE* pdata_current_row = pb->pdata + pb->stride * i;
        fread(pdata_current_row, pb->stride, 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The for loop has `i` decreasing because [pixels are usually stored "bottom-up"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_array_(bitmap_data)) (in BMP at least).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, so nice of you to take the time to write this. Just so I am clear,```BYTE* pdata_current_row = pb->pdata + pb->stride * i;``` sets the pdata_current_row pointer to the point of the buffer at pb->stride * I? Thanks

Comment: @m_ridge Yes. `pb->pdata + pb->stride * i` is equivalent to `&pb->pdata[pb->stride * i]`. It's just creating a temporary alias to that place in memory. In my rewrite, you could also get rid of `pdata_current_row` and just call `fread(&pb->pdata[pb->stride * i], pb->stride, 1, fp)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is reading data from the file `file` into the buffer `pb->pdata`, in chunks of size `pb->stride`, **in reverse order**.  The number of chunks is `pb->height`.

The pointer `pdata` is used to indicate where the next chunk is to be placed in the buffer.  Since the total size of the buffer is `pb->stride * pb->height`, the line

```
pdata  = (BYTE*)pb->pdata + pb->stride * pb->height;
```

sets `pdata` to point to the end of the buffer `pb->pdata` (i.e. pointing to the element after the last one).  When `pb->stride` is subtracted from `pdata` on the first iteration of the loop, `pdata` will then point to the location where the first chunk is to be placed, filling up the **last** `pb->stride` bytes of the buffer.  On successive iterations, `pdata` continues to be decremented, writing chunks into the buffer in reverse order, until the final chunk is placed at the start of the buffer `pb->pdata`.

If you omit the initial addition, then `pdata` would start out pointing to the *beginning* of the buffer, and the subtractions would then make it point *before* the start of the buffer.  Then attempting to read at that location would be out of bounds, and this unsurprisingly causes a crash.

Note that the function isn't actually returning `pb->pdata` but rather `pb->pdata ? 0 : -1`.  This is using the C *ternary operator* and says that if `pb->pdata` is non-NULL, return `0`, otherwise return `-1`.  Now `pb->pdata` would only be NULL if the earlier `malloc` failed (i.e. no memory is available), in which case the whole read loop would be skipped by the `if (pb->pdata)`.  So this is in effect returning 0 for success and -1 for failure, which is also a common idiom.

Comment: Thank you very much. So arithmetic operations on buffers are used to set pointer location?